# Handle click on component inside another component with route?

Tags: vue.js

I have this kind of structure in my template

```
<div to="/route/route1">
     <i class="material-icons">airplay</i>
      <span>Title</span>
      <custom-button @click.native="doSomething"></custom-button>
</div>
```

By clicking custom-button I want to call this methods and navigate to another route

```
doSomething() {
     this.$router.push({path: 'route/route2'});
  }
```

Right now when I click on custom-button I still go to `route1`

Is there a way to make this work with this kind of structure?

Comment: Try `<custom-button @click.native.prevent="doSomething"></custom-button>`

Comment: @talkhabi yes, it worked!